# Converting DE to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

Regarding "2" in the image, we know that $\theta = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$, but I have trouble finding out how $\dot{\theta}$ is calculated from this.
I saw some more examples but they are not helping a lot.

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

$$\dot{x}=(x^2+y^2−1)x+y,\quad \dot{y}=(x^2+y^2−1)y-x$$

and it is known that in polar coordinates

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right),\quad x^2+y^2=r^2$$

therefore by the [derivative of the inverse tangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions#Differentiating_the_inverse_tangent_function) and the quotient and chain rule

\begin{align}\dot{\theta}&=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}\left(\frac{\dot{y}x-\dot{x}y}{x^2}\right)\\&=
\frac{\dot{y}x-\dot{x}y}{x^2+y^2}\\&=
\frac{\Big((x^2+y^2−1)y-x\Big)x - \Big((x^2+y^2−1)x+y\Big)y}{r^2}\\&=
\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{r^2}\\&=
\frac{-r^2}{r^2}\\&=
-1
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to rewrite it as $\tan \theta = y/x$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \tan\theta &= \dot{\theta} \sec^2\theta && \text{(chain rule)} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{y}{x} && \text{(definition)}\\
&= \frac{x\dot{y} - \dot{x}y}{x^2}. && \text{(quotient rule)}
\end{align}
This finishes the left side of the equation by algebraic solution of $\dot{\theta}$, i.e.
$$
\dot{\theta} \equiv \left(\frac{\dot{y}}{x} - \frac{\dot{x}y}{x^2}\right)\cos^2\theta.
$$
Now to find the right side of the equation, simply plug in
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\dot{y}}{x} - \frac{\dot{x}y}{x^2}\right)\cos^2\theta &= \left(\frac{(x^2 + y^2 -1)y - x}{x} - \frac{(x^2 + y^2 - 1)xy + y^2}{x^2}\right) \cos^2 \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}  \\
&= -\left(1 + \frac{y^2}{x^2}\right) \left(1 + \frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)^{-1} \\
&\equiv -1.
\end{align}